# How to read dbf fast in python. dbfread reads dbf file very slow

Tags: python, database, performance, dbf

I use python dbfread to read a 20 MB dbf file, but it performs very slow.

```
 from dbfread import DBF
 for record in DBF('people.dbf'):
     for key, value in record.items():
            try:
                value = str(value)
            except:
                value = value.encode('utf-8')
            print key
            print value
```

if i use "load = true" to load the file first, the search is faster, but it takes a lot of memory.

```
table = DBF('people.dbf', load=True)
```

I found some dbfview application runs pretty fast with my dbf, almost immediately. Anyone have good advise for it, is it because python doesn't have good support for reading dbf ? I download a application call "dbfview" and open the same dbf file, it gets the data almost immediately. Is there anyway to write a code performs like that ?

Comment: Can you give an example of your search?  Which fields, what criteria?

Comment: i want to show all the data in the DBF file. I use for loop to get the items from table. It was very slow, but i use a application calls dbfview, it almost get all the data immediately....